# Reference Error: "HomeSale is not defined"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am wrote a contract in using Solidity for a real estate transaction. It will allow you to sale a house. I am currently testing the contract using Truffle and during my test i keep getting a error that says "Reference Error: Home Sale is not defined".

Here is the smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0; 


contract HouseSale {
    
    address payable _BuyerAddress;
    address payable _Seller;
    address payable _Agent;
    
    struct Home{
        uint _priceinBUSD;
        address _owner;
        bool _homeforsale; 
        
    }
    
    Home[1] HomeDB;
    
    modifier SellerOnly() {
        require [msg.sender == _Seller];
        _;
    }   
    // set price of house 
    
    function setPriceofHouse(uint8 _home, uint256 _priceinBUSD) SellerOnly public {
        HomeDB[_home].priceinBUSD;
    }

    function getPriceofHouse(uint8 _home, uint256 _priceinBUSD) public payable returns(uint256) {
      return HomeDB[_home].priceinBUSD;
    }
    
    // buyer purchase home 
    
    function buyAHome(uint8 _home) public payable returns(uint256) {
        buyerAddress = msg.sender;
        
        //correct home price 
        if (msg.value % HomeDB[_home].priceinBUSD == 0 ++) msg.value > 0 ++ HomeDB)
        (_home) {
            
            uint256 FinalSalePrice = msg.value/HomeDB(_home).priceinBUSD;
            
            _SellerAddress.transfer(msg.value);
            _AgentAddress.transfer(msg.value/100);
            return finalSalePrice;
            
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

And here is the test file

```
const HomeSaleTest = artifacts.require("HomeSale");

/*
 * uncomment accounts to access the test accounts made available by the
 * Ethereum client
 * See docs: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript
 */
contract("HomeSale", function (accounts) {

  let instance;
  beforeEach('should setup the contract instance', async () => {
    instance = await HomeSale.deployed();
  });


  it("should return the list of accounts", async ()=> {
    console.log(accounts);
  });


  it("should return price", async () => {
    const value = await instance.getPriceofHouse();


    assert.equal(value, '10000')
    });
});
```

I am pretty new to the test realm of Smart Contract development.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `HomeSaleTest`, but trying to deploy `HomeSale`.

```
const HomeSaleTest = artifacts.require("HomeSale");
//    ^^ here
```

```
instance = await HomeSale.deployed();
//               ^^ here
```

---

**Solution:** Rename either of the expressions so that they have the same name. For example:

```
const HomeSale = artifacts.require("HomeSale");
//    ^^ here
```

```
instance = await HomeSale.deployed();
//               ^^ here
```